# Why do most special functions not have a multiple zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Why do most special functions not have a multiple zero ?
Let $z$ be a complex number. Let $f(z)$ be a special function meromorphic in the entire complex plane. Then the zero's $x_i$ such that $f(x_i) = 0$ rarely have multiplicity above $1$.

It seems we need to take powers or explicitly multiply to define the function to have multiplicity above $1$.

If we express $f(z) = exp(m(z))(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...$ then by a probabilistic argument , the probability that - assuming there are an infinite amount of zero's - , $x_i = x_j$ is equal to the probability of guessing a real value between $0$ and $1$ correctly.

Although this gives an intuive argument , I feel this is not very good.

The Riemann zeta function serves as a good example. Even if we assume RH to hold it is unknown if any of the zero's have multiplicity , but it appears that all have multiplicity 1.

We can test multiplicity for a certain zero or a finite region with theorems of cauchy such as the argument principle and basicly with integrals. ( contour integrals and restatements and generalizations of it )

Testing multiplicity locally seems quite easy , but why is creating multiplicity in a nontrivial way ( trivial = multiply by $(x-1)^2$ , take $f(x)^2$ etc ) so hard ?

Is it really a matter of statistics or did I overlooked something. Im a bit confused about this.

Can we construct example that have multiple zero's ?

Maybe I should think of this more in terms of polynomials and use another way to detect and create multiplicity ... such as considering the derivates at zero's that make polynomial asymptotics and thereby show multiplicity ?

Maybe I just need more tools ?

For a meromorphic g(z) :
Is there something about integrals or integral transforms involving g(z) that decreases the probability at multiple zero's compared to that of g(z) ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the notion of *special* function. Maybe an aspect of interest: A multiple zero of $f$ is also a common zero of $f$ and $f'$.

Comment: Special function is a mathematical term and is well known.
For starters it has intresting properties and is not an elementary function. Good examples are Euler's Gamma function and Riemann's Zeta function. Other examples are Bessel functions and elliptic integrals. Note however that I required meromorphic on the complex plane.

Comment: I think your heuristic argument about probability is actually pretty good.  A "random" meromorphic function does not likely have multiple zeros, so in order to have multiple zeros, we have to design the function especially for that purpose.  This means that a function designed independently for another purpose (which all the "special" functions are) is not likely to have multiple zeroes.

Comment: About your comment of f and f' that was known to me. But It seems that leads to another statistical argument. However it intresting for solving polynomials ... maybe I will post a question related to that later ( Im going off subject here so I quit )

Comment: @Ted well that seems a nice logic. However it seems much weaker for integer polynomials. It is not so hard to get a polynomial who has no multiplicity and its integral or derivative does. Randomness seems quite 'dubious ' as an argument in math ever since number theory. The reason I consider it dubious is because math has a " structure ". Just like primes are not random and integer polynomials. That does not mean things cannot be understood by statistics , but those statistics have to be proved and are not proofs themselves.

Comment: @mick: Ah, I found something on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_function), but there "is no general formal definition" and the informal one contains the phrase "more or less", so I personally won't call it a mathematical term. Thus I think it just means "function that deserves special interest because it has nice properties that are useful in various mathematical contexts". But precisely that makes the random argument less appealing: The zeroes are *not* randomly distributed. For $\sin$ they are periodic and for $\zeta$, well there's RH.

Comment: I a special function $f$ had a few double roots, then we might actually write it as $f=g^2h$ where $g,h$ are "independent" special functions (i.e. with no common zeroes). For example $\sin(z)+1$ has this property. - My hint about $f$ and $f'$ was intended for the case where $f$ is defined by a differential equation, but maybe useful onlyfor specific cases.

Comment: Well naively using set theory combined with *nonreal* probability yields (1-1/R)^Z where R is the card of the reals , 1/R is the probability of guessing a real , Z is the card of the integers , 1/Z is the probability of guessing an integer. (1-1/R)^Z gives the probability that for an infinite amount of zero's (Z) there in no multiplicity. By expansion we get (1-1/R)^Z = 1-1/R ( replace R by 2^n and N by n and use algebra and set theory ).Hence we get a probabilty of 1/R of getting a multiplicity or equivalently guessing a real. However here we have considered all functions ! This is unformal.

Comment: @mick Of course these statistical arguments are not precise, but they are quite good heuristics and should not be dismissed.  A lot of reasonable conjectures in number theory are obtained by applying such heuristics.  Even for integer polynomials, the probability that a randomly chosen (with any reasonable distribution) such polynomial will have a derivative or antiderivative with multiple zeroes is 0.  You have to design it especially for the purpose.

Comment: But what is it about intresting properties that does not create multiplicity ?